# WPF XAML Style property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm new to `XAML`, how would I go about creating a `Background Gradient Brush`
for a `Canvas` background, where the `Color Gradient` could use the previously defined `Brush` to get a `new Brush`, like so:

```
<Style x:Key="CanvasColorTheme" TargetType="Canvas">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFCCDFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
                <GradientStop <!-- Previous Color / 2 --> Offset="0.50"/>
                <GradientStop <!-- Previous Color / 2 --> Offset="0.70"/>
                <GradientStop <!-- Previous Color / 2 --> Offset="0.95"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>                    
   </Setter>                
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a ResourceDictionary. Here is what I have written inside:

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
     <GradientStop Color="#ECECEC" Offset="0"/>
     <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
     <GradientStop Color="#A0A0A0" Offset="1"/>
 </LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground}"/>
</Style>
```

So as to "activate" the ResourceDictionary you must enter this code insode App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ShinyGrey.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

hope it helps.